# SocketChannel not receiving data with Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have this code which when i call from a standalone java application,it works well in that i can connect to the server send and receive data from the server successfully.

But when i use the same code in an applet,I can connect and send data but cannot receive data and am not getting any error message on either the server or the client.

They are both connecting to the same server application hence am eliminating issues with the server.

i have granted all permissions to the Applet

Your help will be highly appreciated
    Main Application Code
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {  
           List<String> bb=new ArrayList<String>();
           bb.add("Customer");
           bb.add("ID");
           byte [] serialized=ECSStreamUtil.serializeObject(bb);
           ByteBuffer toSend=ByteBuffer.allocate(serialized.length);
           toSend.put(serialized);
           toSend.flip();
           JavaApplication1.write(toSend);
           toSend.clear();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    new JavaApplication1();
```

### JavaApplication1 code

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;

public class JavaApplication1 {
static int x;

private static SocketChannel client ;
public JavaApplication1()throws Exception
{

client = SocketChannel.open();

// nonblocking I/O
client.configureBlocking(false);

 // Connection to host port 4444
 client.connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("localhost",4444));

 // Create selector
 Selector selector = Selector.open();

 // Record to selector (OP_CONNECT type)
SelectionKey clientKey = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
// Waiting for the connection
while (true) 
{
if(selector.select(5000)==0)return ;
// Get keys
Set keys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator i = keys.iterator();


// For each key...
while (i.hasNext())
{
SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)i.next();

// Remove the current key
i.remove();

// Get the socket channel held by the key
SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
if(!channel.finishConnect())
    return;


if(key.isConnectable())
{
    SocketChannel sc=(SocketChannel)key.channel();
    sc.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    System.out.println("conne");
    continue;
}
if(key.isReadable())
{
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(89);
    int x=channel.read(buf);

    if(x==-1)
    {
        key.cancel();
        continue;
    }

    while((channel.read(buf)>0))
    {
        buf.flip();
    }
    byte c[]=buf.array(); 
    System.out.println(new String(c));


    //buf.clear();
}



}
 keys.clear();
 }
 }
 public static void write(ByteBuffer data)
{
try
{    
   client.write(data);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

### Applet Code

```
private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {

           List<String> bb=new ArrayList<String>();
           bb.add("Customer");
           bb.add("ID");
           byte [] serialized=ECSStreamUtil.serializeObject(bb);
           ByteBuffer toSend=ByteBuffer.allocate(serialized.length);
           toSend.put(serialized);
           toSend.flip();
           JavaApplication1.write(toSend);

        //Send information

    }
    catch(Exception io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Am calling this code from the init method in applet

```
try
{
new JavaApplication1();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client reading code is incorrect.

1. If read() returns -1 you should close the channel, not just cancel the key.
2. Your read/flip loop is nonsense. You should read until you have a complete message, however you determine that, *then* flip and get the data from the buffer.

I don't really see why you're using NIO in the client at all, when there is only one connection. There is really zero benefit. I would get it working with java.net in the client and then see whether you have any reason to change it.

Comment: 1.I have closed the channel but still not getting any response.

Comment: 2.The read/flip works perfectly on the standalone application so and not on the applet.Am using NIO because i will deploy this solution using an applet to around 4000 users

Comment: The read/flip doesn't do anything so I don't know what 'works perfectly' can possibly mean. It is meaningless and pointless. If you just want to ignore the data you just read, use clear(). flip() is for when you're about to get data out, and it should always be followed by compact() or clear().

Comment: Finally Worked..only change i made was the return statement to continue. i replaced `if(selector.select(5000)==0)return` with `if(selector.select(5000)==0)continue` still don't understand why the same code behaves different on Applet and Application.